# deduct values of a column in a table from another table

Tags: mysql

i want to deduct the amount of ingredients of a product every time it is ordered

so I have 2 tables, PRODUCT_INGREDIENTS and INVENTORY
I want to deduct the amount of ingredients of a product(PRODUCT_INGREDIENTS), every time it is ordered, in the INVENTORY table

BEFORE ORDERING:

```
PRODUCT_INGREDIENT
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|item_id | ingredient_name | amount |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   2    |      sugar      |  10    |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   2    |      milk       |  15    |
+--------+-----------------+--------+

INVENTORY
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|  id    | ingredient_name | amount |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   1    |      sugar      |  100   |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   2    |      milk       |  100   |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

AFTER ORDERING

```
INVENTORY
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|  id    | ingredient_name | amount |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   1    |      sugar      |   90   |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   2    |      milk       |   85   |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

i want my table to look like that after transaction. how can I do it in MY SQL.
I'm in desperate need of codes

Comment: Have you looked at triggers?

Comment: if you mean mysql UPDATE, yes I know the basics, but I have no idea how to use it when I have 2 or more values to change

Comment: No I don't mean update read up on triggers here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html and google sql triggers for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your INVENTORY table based on what is PRODUCT_INGREDIENT with the following code:

```
 UPDATE INVENTORY i, PRODUCT_INGREDIENT p SET i.amount = i.amount - p.amount WHERE i.id = p.item_id
```

Comment: only the "milk" in INVENTORY changed, and it was deducted with 10 instead of 15

Answer (score 0):

You have to design the table using the table relationship concept using Primary key and Foreign key concept. For example, suppose item_id is the primary key of PRODUCT_INGREDIENT table then make a relationship with the inventory table using the primary key item_id and define it as a foreign key(fk) in the INVENTORY table. Then You can execute query to update the amount in INVENTORY table with the reference of item_id foreign key.

But I think the Best process is using the SQL **TRIGGER** concept for this operation. If you don't know the process then please go through the TRIGGER concept. It is simple.

### Item Table

[image]

### Inventory Table

[image]

Comment: thank you, I'd look into it. the item_id in the PRODUCT_ing refers to the product created in PRODUCT table, that is why it has the same value.
I'd like to upvote you but I can't. I'm still new in stackoverflow

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code

```
 UPDATE INVENTORY i, PRODUCT_INGREDIENT p SET i.amount = i.amount - p.amount WHERE i.ingredient_name = p.ingredient_name
```

I got the idea from mr. mario who answered the question. thank you.